# 'I suppose the country can only properly be given to a child – as from birth it was given to me.' Does this sentence make sense?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, complements

In *The Firstborn*, British author Laurie LEE, famous for his autobiographical novel *Cider with Rosie*, wrote – about his newborn daughter Jessy:

> I suppose the country can only properly be given to a child – as from birth it was given to me. And as it was given to me, so I'd like to show it to her, and see it again through her eyes – the veils of blue rain wandering up from Wales, streaking the sky before they hit the ground; copper clouds of thunder towering over the Severn, mist wiping great holes in the hillside, the beech-tops breaking into a storm of rooks, the light on the cows in the evening....

Isn't the phrase 'from birth' placed in the wrong clause for the first sentence to make sense?
Shouldn't it be

> I suppose the country can only properly be given to a child **from birth** – as it was given to me.

? Isnt' the first clause missing a complement (in what manner or when should the country be given to a child)?

The author must have rewritten the sentence a certain number of times and mixed things up in the end, mustn't he?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase 'from birth' is not in the wrong clause. The sentence can be paraphrased as follows:

> I suppose the country can only properly be given to a child, in the same way as it was given to me from birth.

So, "from birth" refers to the time when "the country" was given to the narrator.

If you rephrase the sentence as follows:

> I suppose the country can only properly be given to a child from birth – as it was given to me.

you leave out the information about *when* it was given to the narrator.

It is not clear why the sentence would need an additional complement. For comparison, here are a few more sentences with "x was/is given to ...":

- Land was given to the Church in perpetuity and until the Reformation could not be sold. ([The National Archives](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/domesday/world-of-domesday/church.htm))
- The vaccine is usually given to babies and children from birth up to the age of 16 who are identified as being at higher risk of the disease compared to the general population. It is also sometimes given to adults up to the age of 35, but the vaccine does not work well in adults. ([Vaccine Knowledge Project](http://vk.ovg.ox.ac.uk/bcg-vaccine))
- What was the name of the first royal corgi, which was given to the Queen on her 18th birthday in 1944? ([*Daily Mail*, January 2011](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-1345988/Royal-Family-quiz-Whats-Prince-Philips-favourite-tipple.html))
- The Little House at Royal Lodge at Windsor was given to the Queen on her sixth birthday. ([*Daily Mail*, February 2012](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2099859/A-Wendy-house-fit-Queen-The-secrets-history-tiny-Welsh-cottage-grounds-Windsor-generations-royals-played.html))

Note: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurie_Lee#Other_works) does not list *The Firstborn* as one of Laurie Lee's autobiographical novels. For this reason, I write "the narrator" instead of "Laurie Lee" or "the author".

Answer (score -1):

Your question asked if the word order given here made sense. Well, seeing as you've found a way to change it so that it makes *more* sense than it did before, you've answered your own question, because the original text made just enough sense to you for you to be able to say to yourself, "Hey, this doesn't look right . . ." and post it here.

In short: No, the phrase 'from birth' ***isn't*** placed in the wrong clause for the first sentence to make sense.

Is it placed in the wrong clause to be grammatically correct? Be damned if I know.

Probably not the the answer you were looking for, but it's the only one I've got now, the only one I probably ever will have. *Plus* it's subject to interpretation.

***Shrug***

Sorry I couldn't be of more help.